# Dynamic Row of Controls on button click in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a row of row of controls which are binded to model properties. I want to have a button which creates another row of such controls binded to same properties. Is there any way to achieve this.

Here is the code:
Model:

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }

   public  List<ProductModel> productList { get; set; }

   public double SubTotalPrice { get; set; }

   public double TotalAmount { get; set; }

   public int ProductID { get; set; }
}
```

And here the row of controls:

```
<tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductName, new SelectList(Model.productList, "ProductID", "ProductName"), "Select")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPrice)</td>
                      <i class="ion-plus-round"
               style="font-size: 25px;
            color: #e67e22;
            margin-left:5px;
            ">
            </i>
        </td>
```

Comment: Your new button is for a newly created product?

Comment: Yes in case he wants to add a new product

Comment: If you want to keep adding new rows for new products without leaving the original page you'll need AJAX. Each button click calls a partial view with a new row which you then append to the table with JavaScript.

Comment: And you are going to have to manually name your controls like @name="Model[0].Price" if you want to be able to post back the collection.

Comment: Name can be same...